# Reinstall TouchWiz Calendar

Tags: calendar, samsung-touchwiz, t-mobile-sidekick-4g

I've been trying to reinstall the TouchWiz calendar on my Sidekick 4G with no luck.

I got the calendar apk [here](https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?hl=en_US&hl=en_US&key=0Ag43oj7rLQP4dENZcmhGN0ZUa3pHSENVeXlqUm5vV0E), and put it on my sd card then moved it to system/app using RootExplorer, and once I clicked install I got the normal install prompts then a message that said "Application not installed".

How can I fix this? Do I need to reinstall a stock ROM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't install system apps, they're automatically detected.  After you move it to `/system/app/` just remount system as read-only and reboot.  If your ROM's not deodexed that may not work but that's a whole other can of worms.

Comment: Thanks, Matt! I set the system/app directory to r/o and made sure that the app had the same permissions as other apps and then reboot. There's no Calendar app showing up in my app drawer, so I'm guessing my ROM might not be deodexed?

Comment: Are there any files in the same directory with .odex file extension?

Make sure that the apk you're using is directly from the rom you're using.